# How to make Yakuake open always on same screen when working with multiple screens?

Tags: multiple-monitors, yakuake

I am working with Yakuake and a global hotkey to quickly open and close it. However, when I have multiple monitors, Yakuake will pop up on the one monitor where the mouse pointer is currently located. To move it to a different screen, I have to close it, move the mouse to the correct screen, and then press the hotkey again.

How can I make Yakuake open always on one particular screen? System's main screen is OK, if general solutions are not available.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu, under Options, there's a sub-category Screen where you can set your preferences for that.